# Weird output for Math.sqrt() in android

Tags: android

So in my app there is this part which uses the quadratic formula to solve a sum. But I get a weird output. This is what I get instead of the actual answer, "NaN or NaN"

This code is executed on the click of a button.

```
h1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
h2 = Double.parseDouble(b);
h3 = Double.parseDouble(c);


                sq2 = (h1 * h1 - 4* 0.5 *h3*h1);
                sq = (h1 * h1 - 4* 0.5 *h3*h1);

                fin = h1 + (Math.sqrt(sq2))/(2* 0.5 * h3); 
                fin2 = (h1 - (Math.sqrt(sq)))/(2* 0.5 * h3); 

                AlertDialog.Builder ans4 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Eq2.this);
                ans4.setTitle("ANSWER");
                ans4.setMessage(fin + " or " + fin2);
                ans4.setPositiveButton("OKAY!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        e4.setText(fin + "or" + fin2); 
                    }
                });
                ans4.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

`NaN` : 'Not a Number'. In other words it went poop!

The reason in your code is almost certainly taking the square root (`Math.sqrt()`) of a negative value.

If you are attempting that, then either

1. your formula is wrong.
2. your formula needs a conditional guard
3. or you need to use complex numbers.

Comment: Check if `h1 >= 2*h3`. If not, you get a negative number. (What is `h2` for anyway?)

Answer (score 1):

When you perform `Math.sqrt` on a negative number you get `NaN` (Not a Number), check your maths.

Using `Math.abs` prior to `Math.sqrt` should get you an number (it makes your input to `Math.sqrt` positive), probably not the right number though;

```
fin = h1 + (Math.sqrt(Math.abs(sq2))/(2* 0.5 * h3); 
fin2 = (h1 - (Math.sqrt(Math.abs(sq))))/(2* 0.5 * h3);
```